# How to filter and get sublist from a FileList in Rake?

Tags: rake, filtering

I don't know Ruby, but *Rake* looks so cool, so I am trying to use it.

When I select files with `FileList["*.cpp"]`, sometimes I want to take filtering out sublist from it.

For source input file,

```
somefile.txt
a.cpp
MySome.cpp
Another.cpp
MySomeValue.cpp

newlist = FileList["*.cpp"].sublistByFiltering("*Value.cpp").sublistByFiltering("My*")
```

And `newlist` shows only `MySomeValue.cpp`.

How can I do this?

**Update**

The method `sublistByFiltering` is my imaginary one, and I am looking for the feature currently in Rake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you came up with this `sublistByFiltering` method, but I think what you're looking for is to do an intersection between the internal arrays of multiple `FileList` items.

```
a = FileList['*.cpp'].to_a
b = FileList['*Value.cpp'].to_a
a & b #=> files that are in both `a` and `b`
```

However, if you know all of the patterns up front, and you're only ever combining them, you can pass a regular expression to the FileList constructor:

```
FileList[/My.*Value\.cpp/]
```

Comment: Can I make FileList back from the internal array?

Comment: Sure, because any entry in the array is just an non-globbing filename you can just pass the entire array as an argument to FileList.new! E.g. `FileList.new(files_I_lurve)`

Comment: By the way, you might want to check out the rest of the FileList docs. The brief at the top explains the basic idea behind the class, and all of the methods (and their individual source) is all available there. http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/FileList.html